# How to Write Characteristics to Bluetooth Low Energy Device Without Paring Every Time?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using the following code from this [site](https://medium.com/@urish/start-building-with-web-bluetooth-and-progressive-web-apps-6534835959a6) to pair and connect to a bluetooth low energy printer via the browser for my asp.net MVC Web App.

```
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
  filters: [{ services: [0xffe5] }]
})
  .then(function(device) {
    // Step 2: Connect to it
    return device.gatt.connect();
  })
  .then(function(server) {
    // Step 3: Get the Service
    return server.getPrimaryService(0xffe5);
  })
  .then(function(service) {
    // Step 4: get the Characteristic
    return service.getCharacteristic(0xffe9);
  })
  .then(function(characteristic) {
    // Step 5: Write to the characteristic
    var data = new Uint8Array([0xbb, 0x25, 0x05, 0x44]);
    return characteristic.writeValue(data);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
     // And of course: error handling!
     console.error('Connection failed!', error);
});
```

This code works perfectly but what I don't understand how to do is to decouple the "Pairing", "Connecting", "Get Service" and "Write Service" from the actual writing of the characteristic. Ideally I would like to pair, connect, get the service and characteristic once.  Then just continually do write values so I can print multiple things without having to have the pairing prompt show up every time. Every example I've seen has them all tied together in the .then format instead of standalone.

Basically how to decouple this:

```
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
  filters: [{ services: [0xffe5] }]
})
  .then(function(device) {
    // Step 2: Connect to it
    return device.gatt.connect();
  })
  .then(function(server) {
    // Step 3: Get the Service
    return server.getPrimaryService(0xffe5);
  })
  .then(function(service) {
    // Step 4: get the Characteristic
    return service.getCharacteristic(0xffe9);
  })
});
```

From This:

```
  .then(function(characteristic) {
    // Step 5: Write to the characteristic
    var data = new Uint8Array([0xbb, 0x25, 0x05, 0x44]);
    return characteristic.writeValue(data);
  })
});
```

Thanks.  This is my first expierence with BTLE so sorry if its a dumb question, but I'm struggling a bit.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in my Angular application was to use the async/await pattern and assign the response object to a globlal variable like this:

```
this.bluetoothDevice = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({acceptAllDevices: true});
```

Then I use another variable to manage the connection:

```
this.serverConnected = await this.connect(this.bluetoothDevice.gatt);
```

And finally, I use those variables in separated methods inside my class to manage the disconnect:

```
onDisconnectButtonClick() {
    if (!this.bluetoothDevice) {
      return;
    }
    console.log('Disconnecting from Bluetooth Device...');
    if (this.bluetoothDevice.gatt.connected) {
      this.bluetoothDevice.gatt.disconnect();
    } else {
      console.log('> Bluetooth Device is already disconnected');
      this.deviceInfo = 'You have been disconnected.'
    }
  }
```

Hope it helps you!